# Hadoop: How to keep track of Clients and client sessions?

Tags: hadoop, clientip

I am trying to find popularity of files present on a client's session. Is there a way to determine the client IP and log the files in a clients session? Or do i have to write my own code or it? If so what are the things to be considered while writing that code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Audit logs are logged from the Hive metastore server for every metastore API invocation. It is logged at the INFO level of **log4j**, so you need to make sure that the logging at the INFO level is enabled. The name of the log entry is **"HiveMetaStore.audit"**.

Audit logs were added in Hive 0.7 for secure client connections and in Hive 0.10 for non-secure connections

Comment: Thanks. I haven't touched Hive yet(I am new to Hadoop). I'll look it up in detail. Can you give me a sample code on how to use the client sessions recorded in audit logs in a java program. Or just the methods or classes i should be concentrating on when trying to achieve this. I am basically trying to find no. of times a file (say X) appears in a session/ total no. of files in that session.

Comment: You can parse log file with java. Also, you can use cloudera navigator for your purpose.